# wild card (asterisk) in Windows batch

Tags: windows, cmd, wildcard

I have this command in my windows's script (.cmd file):

`CALL mv *.exe foo.exe`

The wildcard character doesn't seem to be be interpreted as a wildcard at all, because the when the script is executed, it throws an error about not finding a file with name `*.exe` (literally *.exe). There **is** a .exe file in the current directory, by the way.

So how should I rewrite this command?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `mv` is available, maybe you have `sh.exe` or `bash.exe` nearby. Then it's easy:

```
sh.exe -c "mv *.exe foo.exe"
```

CMD interpreter doesn't expand wildcards, unlike unix shells: commands do (or don't do) it by themselves. Maybe builtin `ren` command will expand wildcard, but I'm unsure.

Comment: Where can I usually find the "sh.exe"? I'll probably need to update my PATH

Comment: Where do you find `mv`? I think sh or bash could be at the same place. Well, maybe not. BTW, I've just tried "ren" with wildcards on CMD.EXE from Wine, and it worked -- so give it a try on real windows.

Answer (score 2):

In windows, you don't need to use 'call' unless calling another batch script.  You also probably want to use the 'move' command instead; this will interpolate the * correctly in windows.

For example, if you use a script that has:

```
move *.exe foo.exe
```

in it, you get an outcome like this:

```
C:\dev\example>dir /B
a.exe
mymove.cmd

C:\dev\example>mymove

C:\dev\example>move *.exe foo.exe
C:\dev\example\a.exe
        1 file(s) moved.

C:\dev\example>dir /B
foo.exe
mymove.cmd

C:\dev\example>
```

Giving exactly the behavior you're looking for!